# Does CompletableFuture have a corresponding Local context?

Tags: java-8, logback, completable-future

In the olden days, we had `ThreadLocal` for programs to carry data along with the request path since all request processing was done on that thread and stuff like Logback used this with `MDC.put("requestId", getNewRequestId());`

Then Scala and functional programming came along and `Future`s came along and with them came `Local.scala` (at least I know the twitter `Future`s have this class).  `Future.scala` knows about `Local.scala` and transfers the context through all the `map`/`flatMap`, etc. etc. functionality such that I can still do `Local.set("requestId", getNewRequestId());` and then downstream after it has travelled over many threads, I can still access it with `Local.get(...)`

Soooo, my question is in Java, can I do the same thing with the new `CompletableFuture` somewhere with `LocalContext` or some object (not sure of the name) and in this way, I can modify Logback MDC context to store it in that context instead of a `ThreadLocal` such that I don't lose the request id and all my logs across the `thenApply`, `thenAccept`, etc. etc. still work just fine with logging and the `-XrequestId` flag in Logback configuration.

EDIT:

As an example.  If you have a request come in and you are using Log4j or Logback, in a filter, you will set `MDC.put("requestId", requestId)` and then in your app, you will log many log statements line this:

```
log.info("request came in for url="+url);
log.info("request is complete");
```

Now, in the log output it will show this:

```
INFO {time}: requestId425 request came in for url=/mypath
INFO {time}: requestId425 request is complete
```

This is using a trick of `ThreadLocal` to achieve this.  At Twitter, we use Scala and Twitter `Future`s in Scala along with a `Local.scala` class.  `Local.scala` and `Future.scala` are tied together in that we can achieve the above scenario still which is very nice and all our log statements can log the request id so the developer never has to remember to log the request id and you can trace through a single customers request response cycle with that id.

I don't see this in Java :( which is very unfortunate as there are many use cases for that.  Perhaps there is something I am not seeing though?

Comment: Simple answer: no. Data should be just passed from one stage to the dependent stages. What you are asking for, is a variant of global variables.

Comment: well, crap, then anyone know how to solve the logback MDC problem then since that is broken in java when using CompletableFuture while it works just fine in scala if you tie it to Local instead of ThreadLocal.  That was a fantastic feature of log4j and logback.

Comment: So this is a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166789). Instead of asking for a local context, you should describe “the logback MDC problem” you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: not really an XY problem though I give logback/log4j as a concrete example as it is now broken using the MDC....log statements no longer contain the correct requestId when mapping over futures.  We fixed this in scala by overriding the MDC to use Local instead of ThreadLocal.  IT seems there is no fix in java(AND I want to use this for a platform issue that it would make stuff really clean...I do use this very sparingly but it solves some really nice problems.

Comment: Just a thought: if `CompletableFuture` had such a context, what would be its behavior for all methods that "merge" independent CF's? For example, `thenCombine()`, `thenCompose()`, `allOf()`…

Comment: @DidierL I would only transfer for thenCompose/thenApply much like twitter futuers(ie. see the scala code...they already have it solved!!!)

Comment: of course, there is discussion here, but they don't get that they broke log4j and logback(slf4j)'s MDC context across futures http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2017-May/047867.html and it can't be fixed except by them as when I bring a library in, I 'cannot' change that library.  They may finally realize it a year later or perhaps someone else can explain it better to them. until then, we have to do our projects in scala(the MDC is too important to be broken).

Comment: Java 9 added some methods to `CompletableFuture` which would make it much easier to propagate the context. For example `newIncompleteFuture​` and `defaultExecutor​` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#newIncompleteFuture--). You'd still have to ensure that the initial future is of the correct subclass though.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann Correct me if I am wrong, but if I bring in a 3rd party library that uses futures, someone would have to fix all the futures in that 3rd party library for the MDC to propagate into that library(and for logging to continue to use the MDC).  ie. twitter's futures actually did that correctly...hopefully scala futures copied that pattern as well.  It's quite amazing and works great.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann The purpose of the feature is that I could bring in 3rd party libs and the Local state travels through all methods still.  ie. java really needs a Local.java that CompletableFuture knows about to make all this work.

Comment: If you have no control over the 3rd party library that neither, providing a custom `CompletableFuture` nor an `Executor` is possible, then how do you assume control over the context association? The 3rd party library could simply return an already existing future, created when other code called the same method. Whose context should be used? The association doesn’t even have to be established by calling a chaining method on the future, e.g. it could be this way: `CompletableFuture<String> f = new CompletableFuture<>(); someExecutor.execute( () -> f.complete("blah") ); return f;`.

Comment: @Holger This is exactly my point in the answer.  Java 'needs' to copy a 'little more' of the twitter futures in scala.  Their Future.scala 'has a' Local.scala (kind of like ThreadLocal) that they capture and save on the thread and then re-instead when functions run so the context flows through 3rd party libraries.  In this way, async contexts would seamlessthrough flow through frameworks from application code through 3rd party back to application code.

Answer (score 2):

If you come across this, just poke the thread here
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2017-May/047867.html

to implement something like twitter Futures which transfer Locals (Much like ThreadLocal but transfers state).

See the def respond() method in here and how it calls Locals.save() and Locals.restort()
https://github.com/simonratner/twitter-util/blob/master/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Future.scala

If Java Authors would fix this, then the MDC in logback would work across all 3rd party libraries.  Until then, IT WILL NOT WORK unless you can change the 3rd party library(doubtful you can do that).

Answer (score 2):

My solution theme would be to (It would work with JDK 9+ as a couple of overridable methods are exposed since that version)

> Make the complete ecosystem aware of MDC

And for that, we need to address the following scenarios:

- *When all do we get new instances of CompletableFuture from within this class?* → We need to return a MDC aware version of the same rather.
- *When all do we get new instances of CompletableFuture from outside this class?* → We need to return a MDC aware version of the same rather.
- *Which executor is used when in CompletableFuture class?* → In all circumstances, we need to make sure that all executors are MDC aware

For that, let's create a MDC aware version class of `CompletableFuture` by extending it. My version of that would look like below

```
import org.slf4j.MDC;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class MDCAwareCompletableFuture<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {

    public static final ExecutorService MDC_AWARE_ASYNC_POOL = new MDCAwareForkJoinPool();

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture newIncompleteFuture() {
        return new MDCAwareCompletableFuture();
    }

    @Override
    public Executor defaultExecutor() {
        return MDC_AWARE_ASYNC_POOL;
    }

    public static <T> CompletionStage<T> getMDCAwareCompletionStage(CompletableFuture<T> future) {
        return new MDCAwareCompletableFuture<>()
                .completeAsync(() -> null)
                .thenCombineAsync(future, (aVoid, value) -> value);
    }

    public static <T> CompletionStage<T> getMDCHandledCompletionStage(CompletableFuture<T> future,
                                                                Function<Throwable, T> throwableFunction) {
        Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        return getMDCAwareCompletionStage(future)
                .handle((value, throwable) -> {
                    setMDCContext(contextMap);
                    if (throwable != null) {
                        return throwableFunction.apply(throwable);
                    }
                    return value;
                });
    }
}
```

The `MDCAwareForkJoinPool` class would look like (have skipped the methods with `ForkJoinTask` parameters for simplicity)

```
public class MDCAwareForkJoinPool extends ForkJoinPool {
    //Override constructors which you need

    @Override
    public <T> ForkJoinTask<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submit(MDCUtility.wrapWithMdcContext(task));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ForkJoinTask<T> submit(Runnable task, T result) {
        return super.submit(wrapWithMdcContext(task), result);
    }

    @Override
    public ForkJoinTask<?> submit(Runnable task) {
        return super.submit(wrapWithMdcContext(task));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        super.execute(wrapWithMdcContext(task));
    }
}
```

The utility methods to wrap would be such as

```
public static <T> Callable<T> wrapWithMdcContext(Callable<T> task) {
    //save the current MDC context
    Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    return () -> {
        setMDCContext(contextMap);
        try {
            return task.call();
        } finally {
            // once the task is complete, clear MDC
            MDC.clear();
        }
    };
}

public static Runnable wrapWithMdcContext(Runnable task) {
    //save the current MDC context
    Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    return () -> {
        setMDCContext(contextMap);
        try {
            return task.run();
        } finally {
            // once the task is complete, clear MDC
            MDC.clear();
        }
    };
}

public static void setMDCContext(Map<String, String> contextMap) {
   MDC.clear();
   if (contextMap != null) {
       MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);
    }
}
```

Below are some guidelines for usage:

- Use the class `MDCAwareCompletableFuture` rather than the class `CompletableFuture`.
- A couple of methods in the class `CompletableFuture` instantiates the self version such as `new CompletableFuture...`. For such methods (most of the public static methods), use an alternative method to get an instance of `MDCAwareCompletableFuture`. An example of using an alternative could be rather than using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...)`, you can choose `new MDCAwareCompletableFuture<>().completeAsync(...)`
- Convert the instance of `CompletableFuture` to `MDCAwareCompletableFuture` by using the method `getMDCAwareCompletionStage` when you get stuck with one because of say some external library which returns you an instance of `CompletableFuture`. Obviously, you can't retain the context within that library but this method would still retain the context after your code hits the application code.
- While supplying an executor as a parameter, make sure that it is MDC Aware such as `MDCAwareForkJoinPool`. You could create `MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor` by overriding `execute` method as well to serve your use case. You get the idea!

You can find a **detailed explanation** of all of the above here in a [post](https://medium.com/asyncparadigm/logging-in-a-multithreaded-environment-and-with-completablefuture-construct-using-mdc-1c34c691cef0) about the same.

Comment: hmmm, not bad though it's too bad it can't work through 3rd party libs as then logging in the 3rd party library breaks :(.  At twitter, logback works through all the futures, while in java, it breaks down in 3rd party libraries that use futures.  Too bad they don't fix the jdk and add a FutureLocal much like Thread Local which is how logback used to do MDC.  With futures, ThreadLocal no longer works and FutureLocal is required but jdk doesn't know of a FutureLocal.