# How to retain slf4j MDC logging context in CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, slf4j, completable-future, mdc

When executing async `CompletableFuture`, the parent threadcontext and moreover the `org.slf4j.MDC` context is lost.

This is bad as I'm using some kind of "fish tagging" to track logs from one request among multiple logfiles.

`MDC.put("fishid", randomId())`

Question: how can I retain that id during the tasks of `CompletableFutures` in general?

```
List<CompletableFuture<UpdateHotelAllotmentsRsp>> futures =
    tasks.stream()
        .map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> businesslogic(task))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List results = futures.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

public void businesslogic(Task task) {
       LOGGER.info("mdc fishtag context is lost here");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the solution from [How to use MDC with thread pools?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19329668/525036) work? Only restriction is that you need to pass the executor in all `*Async()` calls. If you use Spring `@Async` you just have to configure that executor for `@Async`.

Comment: Also closely related, but didn't get an answer: [Does CompletableFuture have a corresponding Local context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933713/does-completablefuture-have-a-corresponding-local-context)

Comment: any solution may work internally with JUST your code.  It won't work through libraries that then use futures as well.  Java will have more and more libraries using future and MDC won't be transferred into it correctly until Java fixes this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The most readable way I solved this problem was as below -

---------------Thread utils class--------------------

```
public static Runnable withMdc(Runnable runnable) {
    Map<String, String> mdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    return () -> {
        MDC.setContextMap(mdc);
        runnable.run();
    };
}

public static <U> Supplier<U> withMdc(Supplier<U> supplier) {
    Map<String, String> mdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    return (Supplier) () -> {
        MDC.setContextMap(mdc);
        return supplier.get();
    };
}
```

---------------Usage--------------

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(withMdc(() -> someSupplier()))
                 .thenRunAsync(withMdc(() -> someRunnable())
                 ....
```

WithMdc in ThreadUtils would have to be overloaded to include other functional interfaces which are accepted by CompletableFuture

Please note that the withMdc() method is statically imported to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks for your improvement. This is even better as my original answer, so I will accept yours instead. It's also more consistent even if only using one single `.supplyAsync()` statement.

Comment: I think the context remains on the worker thread afterwards. Shouldn't it be reset back to the original context afterwards?

Comment: With this code / solution aren't you creating blocking calls (thread will get blocked in get() or run() calls) ? If you're using async / non blocking IO you shouldn't do that, right?

Comment: using get or join is not a proper solution... you're forcing the caller thread to wait on the future

Answer (score 7):

At the end I created a `Supplier` wrapper retaining the `MDC`. If anyone has a better idea feel free to comment.

```
public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier, Executor executor) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new SupplierMDC(supplier), executor);
}

private static class SupplierMDC<T> implements Supplier<T> {
    private final Supplier<T> delegate;
    private final Map<String, String> mdc;

    public SupplierMDC(Supplier<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.mdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        MDC.setContextMap(mdc);
        return delegate.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: trying it, looks good.I was thinking similar, got the code handy :)

Comment: Can you please share the code , how you have used it

Comment: Please note : Usually CompletableFuture is used as a fluid API, so if you chain another supplier with the static supplyAsync method above, it will be a normal supplier and not a SupplierMDC. Thus the MDC context will be lost for subsequent asynch processing

Comment: @Bhushan that's true. Feel free to add your suggestions how that could be solved.

Comment: @Membersound Thanks to your original answer, I refactored it a little bit and added some code-sugar so that it is compatible with the fluidity of CompletableFuture

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56403808/1594534

Comment: using get or join is not a proper solution... you're forcing the caller thread to wait on the future

Answer (score 3):

My solution theme would be to (It would work with JDK 9+ as a couple of overridable methods are exposed since that version)

> Make the complete ecosystem aware of MDC

And for that, we need to address the following scenarios:

- *When all do we get new instances of CompletableFuture from within this class?* → We need to return a MDC aware version of the same rather.
- *When all do we get new instances of CompletableFuture from outside this class?* → We need to return a MDC aware version of the same rather.
- *Which executor is used when in CompletableFuture class?* → In all circumstances, we need to make sure that all executors are MDC aware

For that, let's create a MDC aware version class of `CompletableFuture` by extending it. My version of that would look like below

```
import org.slf4j.MDC;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class MDCAwareCompletableFuture<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {

    public static final ExecutorService MDC_AWARE_ASYNC_POOL = new MDCAwareForkJoinPool();

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture newIncompleteFuture() {
        return new MDCAwareCompletableFuture();
    }

    @Override
    public Executor defaultExecutor() {
        return MDC_AWARE_ASYNC_POOL;
    }

    public static <T> CompletionStage<T> getMDCAwareCompletionStage(CompletableFuture<T> future) {
        return new MDCAwareCompletableFuture<>()
                .completeAsync(() -> null)
                .thenCombineAsync(future, (aVoid, value) -> value);
    }

    public static <T> CompletionStage<T> getMDCHandledCompletionStage(CompletableFuture<T> future,
                                                                Function<Throwable, T> throwableFunction) {
        Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        return getMDCAwareCompletionStage(future)
                .handle((value, throwable) -> {
                    setMDCContext(contextMap);
                    if (throwable != null) {
                        return throwableFunction.apply(throwable);
                    }
                    return value;
                });
    }
}
```

The `MDCAwareForkJoinPool` class would look like (have skipped the methods with `ForkJoinTask` parameters for simplicity)

```
public class MDCAwareForkJoinPool extends ForkJoinPool {
    //Override constructors which you need

    @Override
    public <T> ForkJoinTask<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submit(MDCUtility.wrapWithMdcContext(task));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ForkJoinTask<T> submit(Runnable task, T result) {
        return super.submit(wrapWithMdcContext(task), result);
    }

    @Override
    public ForkJoinTask<?> submit(Runnable task) {
        return super.submit(wrapWithMdcContext(task));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        super.execute(wrapWithMdcContext(task));
    }
}
```

The utility methods to wrap would be such as

```
public static <T> Callable<T> wrapWithMdcContext(Callable<T> task) {
    //save the current MDC context
    Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    return () -> {
        setMDCContext(contextMap);
        try {
            return task.call();
        } finally {
            // once the task is complete, clear MDC
            MDC.clear();
        }
    };
}

public static Runnable wrapWithMdcContext(Runnable task) {
    //save the current MDC context
    Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    return () -> {
        setMDCContext(contextMap);
        try {
            return task.run();
        } finally {
            // once the task is complete, clear MDC
            MDC.clear();
        }
    };
}

public static void setMDCContext(Map<String, String> contextMap) {
   MDC.clear();
   if (contextMap != null) {
       MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);
    }
}
```

Below are some guidelines for usage:

- Use the class `MDCAwareCompletableFuture` rather than the class `CompletableFuture`.
- A couple of methods in the class `CompletableFuture` instantiates the self version such as `new CompletableFuture...`. For such methods (most of the public static methods), use an alternative method to get an instance of `MDCAwareCompletableFuture`. An example of using an alternative could be rather than using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...)`, you can choose `new MDCAwareCompletableFuture<>().completeAsync(...)`
- Convert the instance of `CompletableFuture` to `MDCAwareCompletableFuture` by using the method `getMDCAwareCompletionStage` when you get stuck with one because of say some external library which returns you an instance of `CompletableFuture`. Obviously, you can't retain the context within that library but this method would still retain the context after your code hits the application code.
- While supplying an executor as a parameter, make sure that it is MDC Aware such as `MDCAwareForkJoinPool`. You could create `MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor` by overriding `execute` method as well to serve your use case. You get the idea!

With that, your code would look like

```
List<CompletableFuture<UpdateHotelAllotmentsRsp>> futures =
    tasks.stream()
        new MDCAwareCompletableFuture<UpdateHotelAllotmentsRsp>().completeAsync(
            () -> businesslogic(task))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List results = futures.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

public UpdateHotelAllotmentsRsp businesslogic(Task task) {
       LOGGER.info("mdc fishtag context is not lost here");
}
```

You can find a **detailed explanation** of all of the above here in a [post](https://medium.com/asyncparadigm/logging-in-a-multithreaded-environment-and-with-completablefuture-construct-using-mdc-1c34c691cef0) about the same.

Answer (score 0):

YES, Twitter Future did this correctly.  They have a class Local.scala that Future.scala knows about.

The fix is for java authors to fix this issue so your Local state travels through ALL libaries that use CompletableFutures.  Basically, Local.scala is used by Future and internally uses a ThreadLocal up until .thenApply or .thenAccept and it will capture state and transfer it when needed to the next one on and on.  This works through all third party libraries with ZERO 3rd party library changes.

Here is more but poke Java Authors to fix their stuff...
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2017-May/047867.html

until then, MDC will NEVER work through 3rd party libraries.

My SO post on this 
[Does CompletableFuture have a corresponding Local context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933713/does-completablefuture-have-a-corresponding-local-context?noredirect=1#comment89808671_37933713)

Comment: The other option being to have EVERY 3rd party library that uses CompletableFuture to switch to a new kind of Future that we all do.  heh, good luck with that one though!